# How to call web api get method in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, asp.net-web-api

Hi i am developing web api application with angular2 application. I am trying to make get request as below.

Below is my angularjs code. In the below code role  is optional parameter.

```
var role = "SUPER_ADMIN";
    var url = '/api/users/' + role;
    return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
```

This is my controller code.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
  public class usersController : ApiController
 {
        [LoginCheck]
        [SuperAdmin]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string role)
        {
         //business logic here
        }
 }
```

I have one more get method as below. This gets called insted of above.

```
 [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("me")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
    }
```

Aboce code does not works. May I get some help here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: any error in console

Comment: Yes thank you. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) http://localhost:22045/api/users/SUPER_ADMIN

Comment: try put `[HttpGet]` before this line public `HttpResponseMessage Get(string role)`. 405 means **The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.**

Comment: Try changing parameter name to "id" instead of "role".

Comment: Thank you. That works. But as i told earlier i have one more Get method. I posted above. when i make http://localhost:22045/api/users/me/ request i am redirecting to first method.

Comment: have you tried somthing like:  public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]string role)

Answer (score 0):

Could you not put [Route] attribute on both your actions and enable AttributeRouting in your api?  So, if you do this, then you are calling your endpoints by specifying the action name which is specific. So something like this:

```
    [LoginCheck]
    [SuperAdmin]
    [Route("AdminGet/{role}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string role)
    {
     //business logic here
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("me")]
    [Route("UserGet")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
    }
```

and your endpoints become:
http://servername/api/users/adminget?role="something"
http://servername/api/users/userget